# AssetPackExtractionService class added to my manifest

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-service

I recently saw an entry like this in my merged manifest after I compiled my app:

```
<!-- The services will be merged into the manifest of the hosting app. -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackExtractionService"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>
```

I had never noticed this kind of entry before. Does anyone know how that could have been introduced into my app?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out ?

Comment: Yep. It seems it somehow got injected from Gradle (it's present in both Gradle 6.5 and 7.02); it appears in their "classAnalysis.bin" files.

Answer (score 1):

it's highly likely you're using navigation-dynamic-features-fragment lib in build.gradle

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$libraries.navigationVersion"
```

Try to remove it if you're not planning to build bundle.